# How can I reduce reactjs file size in production?

Tags: reactjs

I’ve built a simple react app fetching data from a REST API using axios.

Only three packages are imported

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';
```

However, when I run “npm run build” to create my production package I was astonished to see a main.xxxx.js file with 137 kb in size and an additional main.xxx.js.map with 606 kb.

Why are these files so huge? Is there a way to reduce the file sizes?

Comment: If you are using vscode, you can use this extension to see how much the import costs: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost

For example you can only import render from react-dom. Also what does npm run build stand for in your package.json, what do you use as a bundler? what is its configuration for production?

Comment: Note sourcemap files won’t be downloaded by your users unless they open DevTools. So counting them is meaningless. You can also delete them.

Answer (score 1):

The [official source](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#reduced-file-size) stated that v16.0 is `109 KB`.
`axios.min.js` is `13 KB`, so `137 KB` sounds about right if you are at v16.3.

We should be looking at the size with [gzip](/questions/tagged/gzip) since that's what your clients will be served.
Here's a comparison with other popular frameworks:

```
Name          | Size (gzipped)
------------- | -------------
Angular 2     | 111 KB
React 16.2    | 32 KB
Vue 2.5       | 21 KB
```

If you are still concerned with the size, you can try out [preact](https://www.npmjs.com/package/preact), which is only about `4 KB` and has near identical API as React (with a few features stripped).