# create REACT project

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dependencies

I am creating an enterprise app with many, many react.js apps, angular.js apps, android apps etc...

If I use :

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```

It gives me a project with a size of 100MB or less. I don't need most of the libraries in this sample. I just want to create react app with 10MB  maximum size.

What should I do to get a very simple project with the minimum amount of dependencies in React, the simple project that programmers can understand and read easily is my first priority.

Comment: There are a lot of predefined setups but this explains bit more : https://github.com/ahfarmer/minimal-react-starter
However, to talk to backend and use observables you need to add it yourself.

Comment: webpack has [tree shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), your production build will only be a few hundred KB. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50187396/how-can-i-reduce-reactjs-file-size-in-production/50187654#50187654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create-react-app` is development build of the app, so it will be really hard to get the size to under 10MB. But the `production build` of the same will be really small. If you create the `production build` of the default `create-react-app` it will be around 600-700 kB.

This is because `create-react-app` development build contains babel, webpack and all which makes your coding experience a lot better. When it is build for production, webpack and other `dev-dependencies` will be removed. I would suggest you not to worry much about the size of the `development build` and concentrate more on the size only for the `production build`. And since you said *simple project that programmers can understand and read easily is my first priority*, `create-react-app` will take away most of the complications associated with setting up a react app from scratch, such as configuring `dev-server` and `babel`.

Comment: thanks for help i saw that is really simple. i was used "-o appname", i just don't know how add references of the folders to my html page.   folders is much. in other projects i just use some js file and run project, but here i have 125 folders  :(  .